# Wheres my css styling gone?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have an issue in internet explorer 8 and above. I create dynamic content from sitecore, but once I add over a certain number of items on the page of that one item type my css from a certain section of the page decides not to style its content bizarre.

I know there is quite a lot below but this set of code gets created multiple times when I create an item in sitecore:

Front End HTML:

```
<div class="<%=uniqueID %>">
    <div class="compareRatesSlideSpot">

         <div class="headerContent">
                <div class="tableContainer">
                    <div class="exchangeProvider"><%=exchangeProvider %></div>
                    <div class="exchangeRate"><%=exchangeRate %></div>
                    <div class="transferCharges"><%=transferCharges %></div>
                    <div class="amountYouGet"><%=amountYouGet %></div>
                </div>
                <div class="Toggle">
                    <span> 
                        Learn more <img src="/images/arrow_open.png" /> 
                    </span>
                </div>
          </div>



          <div class="Content">

            <%=content %>

          </div>



    </div>
    <div class="Shadow"></div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".<%=uniqueID %> .headerContent").css("color", "<%=fontColor %>");
        $(".<%=uniqueID %> .tableContainer").css("background-color", "<%=bgColor %>");
        $(".<%=uniqueID %> .Toggle").css("color", "#000000");
    }); 

    var <%=uniqueID %>isToggled = 0;

    $(".<%=uniqueID %> .Toggle").hover(
      function () {
          $(this).css("color", "<%=secondaryColor %>");
      },
      function () {
          $(this).css("color", "#000000");
      }
    );

  $(".<%=uniqueID %> .Toggle").click(function () {

      $(".<%=uniqueID %> .Content").slideToggle("slow");
    if (<%=uniqueID %>isToggled == 0) {
        <%=uniqueID %>isToggled = 1;
        $(".<%=uniqueID %> .Toggle span").html('Minimise <img src="/images/arrow_close.png" />');
    } else if (<%=uniqueID %>isToggled == 1) {
        <%=uniqueID %>isToggled = 0;
        $(".<%=uniqueID %> .Toggle span").html('Learn more <img src="/images/arrow_open.png" />');
    };

});
</script>
```

I need a second pair of eyes to help find whats going wrong, I have been staring at it for hours and still no success.

**Solution:**

Sigh it turned out we had the css link for the user control within the user control, which is loaded into different master pages. I put the relevant css link into the head of each master page, works fine now. Thanks to the answer below I was able to debug it down to this problem.

Comment: You need to figure out if the HTML/CSS/JS isn't doing what you think it should or if the ASP isn't generating the HTML/CSS/JS you think it should be. Showing server side code when you have a client side symptom isn't all that helpful.

Comment: Any valid reason that you're adding well-supported style properties through jQuery instead of `<style>`?

Comment: The styles come from the cms where the content editors have several options to customise page features, I use javascript to set the values from the cms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the question goes one can only guess.

As you say that everything is OK until you add some extra HTML elements I would say that you probably should validate your HTML. Pass it [through the W3C validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) and try to understand what's going wrong.

I've experience similar behaviour by leaving an element open.

```
<div>
    ....
<div> <!-- forgot to close the div and actually oppened a new one -->
      <!-- can mess with the whole layout -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using AJAX on the form? Are you adding HTML on submit (like after some input from user)? If both answers are yes then the answer is that doucment.ready() function don't get called after ajax postback. You need to call javascript using ScriptManager.

If you are not using Ajax then you need to validate your HTML with [W3C School HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Developer Tool in IE8 and check what stypes are being applied...   You can debug Javascripts as well.